# Use and change variable for blocks instead of directly hardcoding

Tags: static-block, configuration

I created a module for viewing bestseller products  :

In my **Catalog/Block/Product/Bestseller.php**, I have this line :

```
 $products->setPageSize(6)->setCurPage(1);
                 //-----^
```

In **`CMS`**-->**`pages`**-->**`Home`**-->**`contents`**, I have :

```
{{block type="catalog/product_bestseller" template="catalog/product/bestseller.phtml"}}
```

I want to use some sort of configuration instead of hard coding the '***6***' in my code.

By example, I want to add `number_count="6"` to the page's content (in block tag),And instead of using '***6***' in the **Bestseller.php**, I want to use something like : `$this->number_count`, How can I  achieve this ?

Comment: http://www.proxiblue.com.au/blog/smarter-cms-category-product-limits/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an alternative way of what [Sonassi](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/361/sonassi) has answered, if you do not need to change page size i.e. page size is fixed and you rarely change it. In that case it will be better to create a permanent setting.
You can insert a row in core_config_data table of magento (by system.xml of a module or plane sql insert). Now you can call this setting by Mage::getStoreConfig('a/b/c') where "a/b/c" is the path and you will get value that you inserted in table.

```
$products->setPageSize(Mage::getStoreConfig('a/b/c'))->setCurPage(1);
```

Comment: I want to change the page size, in the future( by shop's manager).

Comment: and how am I supposed to change it in this way?

Comment: And by the way, @sonnassi 's answer is not working at all

Comment: If you have not created your own module, go to any built in module and locate system.xml in etc directory of your module. Now create an entry in this xml file as shown here - http://excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-part8-series-systemxml

Answer (score 1):

Just define the variables you need in the block shortcode definition.

```
{{block type="catalog/product_bestseller" template="catalog/product/bestseller.phtml" block_count="6"}}
```

Then retrieve using the normal Magento magic getter.

```
$pageSize = ($this->hasBlockCount()) ? $this->getBlockCount() : 6;
$products->setPageSize($pageSize)->setCurPage(1);
```

Comment: It's not working, `$this->hasBlockCount()` returns `FALSE`